# How add key to dictionary without value?

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, addition

in normally we should add `key` and `value` together in `dictionary type`. like:

```
myDict.Add(key1, value1);
myDict.Add(key2, value2);
```

I want to know, Is there any way to add `key` first, then insert its `value`? (not both of them at the same time)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If the `value` type of the dictionary is nullable, you could add a null value:

```
myDict.Add(key1, null);
```

If the `value` is non nullable, you can use a default value, either `default` or some out of range value, depending on your expected meaningful values.

```
myDict.Add(key1, default(int));
myDict.Add(key1, Int32.MinValue);
```

### But

as mentioned in the comments, there is no discernible merit in doing this. You can add values at any time, there is no need to pre-initialize a dictionary with keys.

Comment: There is a merit. I want to have a nested dictionary the keys are to be assigned later in the program. So, I need them keys forehand.

Comment: There's merit if you plan on iterating through keys